What is the actual weight of the bitcoin blockchain?
In several websites, I read different current size of bitcoin blockchain:

https://ycharts.com/indicators/bitcoin_blockchain_size
and
https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/charts/blocks-size

both say around 620GB.

https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin/

say around 490GB.

https://www.statista.com/statistics/647523/worldwide-bitcoin-blockchain-size/

say around 600GB, but below in the page it's written

Bitcoin's blockchain size was close to reaching 5450 gigabytes in 2024

??? what do these 5.4TB come from?
And why there are incongruences among different websites? Maybe bitinfocharts.com only considers blocks without indexes? Answer is no, because for example the above ychars.com and blockchain.com websites (which both gives 620GB) tell that indexes are not included, so...

The answer below gives good discussion of the legitimate differences, but the Statista article text is just bizarre. I wonder if it's AI-generated or something.

My node currently reports:
$ bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
{
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 873668,
  "headers": 873668,
  "bestblockhash": "00000000000000000001b0251f80ba44e47217f661a06628f48eb71d659ce0eb",
  "difficulty": 103919634711492.2,
  "time": 1733586184,
  "mediantime": 1733584532,
  "verificationprogress": 0.9999971534840028,
  "initialblockdownload": false,
  "chainwork": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000009ef4d8bff5438c3689882eee",
  "size_on_disk": 706175424632,
  "pruned": false
}

size_on_disk "accounts for block files and undo data, and not for chainstate or any indexes you may have enabled  on the block data" (H/T Pieter Wuille in comments). This includes stale blocks and invalid blocks the node may have downloaded and validated. 706,175,424,632 bytes translate to about 657.68 GiB. Only the block data of the best chain should even be a little smaller, so 620 GiB might fit that.
I don’t know how bitinfocharts.com gets only 490 GiB. They must be using a different methodology. Perhaps they are providing a sum of the total serialized block data instead of the size of a node’s block files, but that’s just a guess.
From your source at Statista.com:

Bitcoin's blockchain size was close to reaching 5450 gigabytes in 2024, as the database saw exponential growth by nearly one gigabyte every few days.

I have no idea how Statista arrived at "5450 gigabytes", and the blockchain does not grow exponentially, it is growing linearly at no more than 4 GiB per week. It could briefly grow faster if the hashrate suddenly increases, but the difficulty adjustment would quickly correct that.
